# Autofill field when selecting(searching) another field with data from database in razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have fields, such as Company, First Name, Last Name, so when i select Last Name from list provided by database, i want to autofill other fields.How can i achieve this?

**Action method:**

```cs
    public static IList<Adresse> GetAdresses(string lastname)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Adresse WHERE 
        lastname like  '%{0}%'", lastname);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = CreateDataAdapter(sql);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        IList<Adresse> list = new List<Adresse>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
        Adresse item = new Adresse();
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dr.Table.Columns)
        {
        PropertyInfo p = item.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ColumnName);
        if (p != null && dr[dc] != DBNull.Value && p.CanWrite)
        {
        p.SetValue(item, dr[dc], null);
        }
        }
        list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

**View**:

```
<div class="table_row">
  <div class="table_cell" style="padding-bottom:5px;"> Firstname: </div>
  <div class="table_cell" style="padding-bottom:5px;"> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.head.FirstName) </div>
</div>
<div class="table_row">
  <div class="table_cell" style="padding-bottom:5px;"> LastName: </div>
  <div class="table_cell" style="padding-bottom:5px;"> 
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.head.LastName, selectList, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker", @Value = @Model.head.FirstName, //onchange = "this.form.submit();" }) 
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
          liveSearch: true,
          showSubtext: true
        });
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to fill company and first name and after selecting last name? Do you have a controller action which receives last name as parameter and returns the other fields?

Comment: Yes, i have a method which returns list of models, according to where clause

Comment: Add it to your question than.

Comment: Added, tried to format it, but not good enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery you can make an ajax request to an action in your controller which will return the addresses information.

```
$("#dropdownlist").change(function() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'GetAddress',
        data: { lastname: $("#dropdownlistID").val() },
        success: function (data) {
            // fill address with data
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            console.log('Failed to retrieve data. Exception: ' + ex);
        }
    });
});
```

Change the signature of your `GetAddress()` method to this:

```
public ActionResult GetAddress(string lastname)
{
    // your code to return address information
}
```

Comment: i'm going to do kind of live search with autocomplete from database, does it work for it?

Comment: Yes, with [autocomplete()](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) but the logic is the same.